# Github API: Mulitple parameters not Working

Tags: api, github, curl

**ENVIRONMENT:** Ubuntu 20.04

**TASK:** Mine all closed bug reports (issues) with the label 'incorrect' from the repository [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible).

**SOLUTIONS:** I have tried using Github's REST API via the curl command. However, curl is either stalling or simply producing a server error. I have not seen much usage of how to include multiple parameters or working with large requests even from the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#comments)

First thing I tried was to mine just the closed issues, below mines all the closed issues or so it seems. It looks like it only includes a couple which leads me to think there are 'pages' to large requests?

```
 curl "https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/issues?state=closed" > closed_issues
```

However the 'labels' is not working for me neither is combining the two. I get a "server_error" and it stops there.

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/issues?state=closed&labels=incorrect" > labeled_closed_issues
```

Comment: There is no `incorrect` label defined in the ansible repo on Github.

Comment: Even with the label "bug", it results in the same.

Comment: It seems Github currently experiences difficulties rendering the pages / API responses for those queries as even the [filtered issues page](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/labels/bug) runs into a timeout. You may want to contact Github Support here as this is nothing Stack Overflow could help you with.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to server issues of GitHub. You may contact their support channels instead.